# SUM AND GROUP OUTPUT BY DAY SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I can not reference by the aliases Gross_Demand and Units.

```
,(CASE WHEN CONCAT(',',post_event_list,',') LIKE '%,1,%' THEN SPLIT(item, ";")[safe_offset(3)] END) Gross_Demand
  ,(CASE WHEN CONCAT(',',post_event_list,',') LIKE '%,1,%' THEN SPLIT(item, ";")[safe_offset(2)] END) Units
```

Comment: Hi Vivaan, welcome to Stack Overflow. We are a helping community, but we cannot do the work for you. Please make your question is as generic as possible, so that you make it easy for other people with the same problem to grasp both the question and find an answer also for their situation. Specifically, ask yourself how you can reduce the SQL statement to the essence for the problem at hand.

Answer (score 0):

Intentionally not giving you a specific answer, but I would structure your query like this:

```
-- Declare your variables
DECLARE StartDate...

with hits as (
  -- select what you need from your hits table, filter and unnest here
),
products as (
  -- select and filter what you need from your products table here
),
joined as (
  -- join the two sources together and do any additional filtering
  select 
    date, visits, orders, gross_demand, units, etc...
  from hits
  join products
),
calcs as (
  select
    *,  
    gross_demand*units as revenue,
    orders/visits * 100 as conversion_pct,
    gross_demand*units/visits as revenue_per_visit
  from joined
)
select * from calcs
```

Breaking down your logic into steps/chunks often makes things way easier.

Comment: My issue with the current formula is that I can not reference the lines below as there alias names. Gross Demand and Units.

  ,(CASE WHEN CONCAT(',',post_event_list,',') LIKE '%,1,%' THEN SPLIT(item, ";")[safe_offset(3)] END) Gross_Demand

  ,(CASE WHEN CONCAT(',',post_event_list,',') LIKE '%,1,%' THEN SPLIT(item, ";")[safe_offset(2)] END) Units

Comment: Keep adding CTEs if you need to.  You can always reference anything that is defined above.